# How to create a Lockfree collection of collection

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, lock-free, concurrent-programming

I need to create a collection of collections. The collection is called by multiple threads to add items and lookup items. Once added the items will not be removed. Currently, while adding elements I need to take a lock on the entire collection. Is there a way around it to make it lockfree. Or is there a better datastructure or pattern that I can use?
Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>> dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>>();

void AddUpdateItem(string s, int k, int v)
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> subDict;
    if (dict.TryGetValue(s, out subDict))
    {
        subDict[k] = v;
    }
    else
    {
        lock (dict)
        {
            if (dict.TryGetValue(s, out subDict))
            {
                subDict[k] = v;
            }
            else
            {
                subDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
                subDict[k] = v;
                dict[s] = subDict;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd` is thread safe (although not atomic). It guarantees that the returned object is the same for all threads. Your code could be rewritten as:

```
void AddUpdateItem(string s, int k, int v)
{
    var subDict = dict.GetOrAdd(s, _ => new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>());
    subDict[k] = v;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make a hashtable lock-free, by using immutability, but it isn't likely to be efficient if there's contention.  Basically, you need a dictionary-content class that can be atomically swapped.  You build a copy of the current-content, with the one change made, then use a compare-and-swap primitive to exchange it with the existing version.  If compare-and-swap fails, start over with the copying step.

You might be able to atomically swap just a single hash-bucket, which would make contention much less common, and retry cheaper.  (`ConcurrentDictionary` does already use this optimization, to reduce lock contention)  But growing the number of buckets will still require the method outlined above.

Have a look at Eric Lippert's blog, in which he covers immutable data structures.  He's got [a nice example of a binary tree](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/18/immutability-in-c-part-six-a-simple-binary-tree.aspx), which should show you the techniques needed to make a lockless hash-table.

Comment: Thanks! that helps. Also thanks for your clarification on the internals of ConcurrentDictionary. (I had always assumed it was lockfree).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using tasks or threads in your code ? In any case, `ConcurrentDictionary` is designed to be thread-safe. You don't need to use locks while add or remove elements. Link from MSDN [How to: Add and Remove Items from a ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997369.aspx)  explains how to use it.

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary` isn't lockfree.

Comment: Sure ConcurrentDictionary is threadsafe but in this case its not safe to add new keys to the 'dict' dictionary. For example, if my calls look like 

    Task.Factory.StartNew( () => AddUpdateItem('a', 1, 2) );
    Task.Factory.StartNew( () => AddUpdateItem('a', 3, 2) );

it would not be threadsafe to add items without taking a lock.

Comment: I was just referring to TryAdd. As mentioned in the article, GetOrAdd and AddOrUpdate are not atomic. Your AddUpdateItem falls under AddorUpdate ?

Answer (score 0):

If you speculatively create the sub-dictionary, there is a simpler solution:

```
readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>> dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>>();

void AddUpdateItem( string s, int k, int v )
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> subDict;

    while ( true )
    {
        if ( dict.TryGetValue( s, out subDict ) )
        {
            subDict[ k ] = v;
            break;
        }

        // speculatively create new sub-dictionary
        subDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
        subDict[ k ] = v;

        // this can only succeed for one thread
        if ( dict.TryAdd( s, subDict ) ) break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

before you go down the road of implementing a lockless collection have a look at [ReadWriteLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) which solve your problem.  If it doesn't (e.g. because you have heavy write contention) there isn't really a one-size-fits-all approach.

One technique I ave used in the past is to have a thread dedicated thread to managing the collection and use `Interlocked.Exchange` to marshal new objects to that thread and an immutable collection out. With this approach your writer threads are managed in a separate list that you need to lock whenever a writer is created or destroyed, so this only works if that is a rare event.